# How do I reset a Page(component) with Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I do not want my pages to save. Currently they save when going to a new route, but I do not want this to happen. I also wanted to know how could I reset my Provider (service) also.

Currently I am pushing the next navigation to NavController, is there another way to do this so it doesn't save?

Comment: What do you mean by 'saving' and 'resetting'? I don't fully understand your problem. Do you have an example?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't understand at first was that pushing onto navController saves the history and when the same page comes again it has the history from last time.

The solution is to just setRoot instead

```
 navController.setRoot(...Page);
```